# Rewrite condition on Drupla7 without prefix 'www'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7, wamp

I just wanted to redirect all users to access the site with the 'www.' prefix  (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)

I have added the default code in drupal 7 .htaccess.

It was working perfectly in Mozilla and Chrome and not in IE.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please advice this to work in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your  .htaccess lines to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in your apache setup. I would not do it in .htaccess file.

In your

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/SITENAME

do something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName http://www.example.com
 Redirect / http://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```